# how to redirect different domains to their respective application ports

Tags: apache, spring-boot, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have VPS and currently i am running 5 Spring boot applications on that server along with `httpd`.
all html for those applications are inside their respective jars. All of them having different domain names. So after hitting the dns name it should automatically go that port application, right now i need to specify the port number explicitly like `example.com:9090` i tried virtual host in httpd.conf but its not working.

```
Listen 9001

<VirtualHost *:9001>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.askcomputers.co.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2.com
    ServerName www.example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make sure that you have the proper modules installed for httpd:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Then I think you should have 5 VirtualHost sections with reverse proxy setup:

```
<VirtualHost www.example1.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.askcomputers.co.in
    ServerName www.example1.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9090
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090
</VirtualHost>
...
<VirtualHost www.example5.com:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.askcomputers.co.in
    ServerName www.example5.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9094
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9094
</VirtualHost>
```